# problem writing regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches only any of the following:

```
{string}
{string[]}
{string[6]}
```

where instead of `6` in the last line, there could be any positive integer. Also, wherever `string` appears in the above lines, there could be `int`.

Here is the regular expression I initially wrote : `{(string|int)(([]|[[0-9]])?)}`. It worked well but wouldn't allow more than one digit within the square bracket. To overcome this problem, I modified it this way : `{(string|int)(([]|[[0-9]*])?)}`.

The modified regex seems to be having serious problems. It matches `{string[][]}`. Can you please tell me what causes it to match against this? Also, when I try to enclose `[0-9]` within paranthesis, I get an exception saying "`too many )'s`". Why does this happen?

Can you please tell me how to write the regular expression that would satisfy my requirements?

Note : I am tryingthis in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters like {} and []:

```
\{(string|int)(\[\d*\])?\}
```

You might need to use `[0-9]` instead of \d depending on the engine you use.

Comment: I am trying using C#. Looks like the {,},[,] do not need to be escaped. Attempt to escape them is leading to error. \d doesn't work either

Comment: If you use regular strings you need to do double backslash instead of just one backslash. Alternatively you can use `@""` strings, in which you don't need double escaping.

Comment: making the regex a raw string solved the problem. your solution worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `[` as it indicates a character set in regular expressions; otherwise `[[0-9]*]` would be interpreted as character class of `[` and `0`–`9`, `*` quantifier, followed by a literal `]`. So:

```
{(string|int)(\[[0-9]*])?}
```

And since the quantifier `*` allows zero repetitions too, you don’t need the special case for an empty `[]`.

Comment: I am trying this using C#. When I use the above regex, the compiler complains that '\\[' is not a recognized escape sequence

Comment: making the regex a raw string solved the problem. your solution worked. thanks!